# Find duplicate values in pairs - select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, duplicates

I have pair of text boxes. I need to find duplicate pair values in my select dropdown.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sL6ofchd/8/) example

```
txt12    txt12
txt2     txt1
txt3     txt3
txt4     txt5
txt12    txt12
```

In my example, txt12 select pair is duplicated. I could possibly find each duplicate values by considering each select dropdowns.

```
 var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 var values = [];
 for(i=0;i<selects.length;i++) {
    var select = selects[i];
    if(values.indexOf(select.value)>-1) {
        alert('duplicate - '+select.value); break;
    }
    else 
        values.push(select.value);
 }
```

How is it possible to find **duplicate pair** of select dropdown values

Comment: Could you give an example of what output you want, I'm unsure what you mean by *"duplicate pair"*, as in pair of what?

Comment: it is working fine. but the problem is with the alert

Comment: i have updated my fiddle.. I'm having multiple pairs of select dropdowns which are duplicate. and i need to find duplicate select dropdown pairs

Comment: yes it is working fine.

Comment: What about removing the `break` so it doesn't stop at the first one?

Comment: Removing break will check all selects, if there is duplicate, alert will execute. I want to find the combination duplication

Comment: I believe you are looking for this -> http://jsfiddle.net/dtrx33fg/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
function chkVal() {
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    var values = [];
    for(i=0;i<selects.length;i++) {
        var select = selects[i];
        if(values.indexOf(select.value)>-1) {
            alert('duplicate - '+select.value);
        }
        else 
            values.push(select.value);
    }
}
```

You have to just remove the `break` in the `if` block as it is moving out of the `for` loop in the first loop when it find `text12`.

Refer to the fiddle : "http://jsfiddle.net/sL6ofchd/9/"

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, try something like this:

```
$('.check-value').on('click', function() {
    var duplicates = $('select+br').prev().filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $(this).prev().val();
    });
    console.log( duplicates.length );
});
```

```js
$('.check-value').on('click', function() {
  var duplicates = $('select+br').prev().filter(function() {
     return $(this).val() == $(this).prev().val();
  });
  console.log( duplicates.length + ' duplicates' );
  duplicates.each(function(i) {
    console.log( i, this, $(this).prev()[0] );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="txt12">txt12</option>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select>
    <option value="txt12">txt12</option>
</select><br><br>


<select>
    <option value="txt2">txt2</option>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select>
    <option value="txt1">txt1</option>
</select><br><br>


<select>
    <option value="txt3">txt3</option>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select>
    <option value="txt3">txt3</option>
</select><br><br>


<select>
    <option value="txt12">txt12</option>
</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select>
    <option value="txt12">txt12</option>
</select><br><br>


<input type="button" value="save" class="check-value">
```